# Compute the indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't quit understand what the question wants me to do here with 'by choosing $u'(x) = x$ and $v(x) = ln(x)$'

This is what I am supposed to integrate by parts by "choosing"what am I supposed to do with these u's and v's?
$$\int \:x\ln \left(x\right)dx$$

but wait it asks to do the other way around as well....

Comment: Literally, any video/ article on integration by parts should cover this..

Comment: Do you know $\int u' \, v \,dx=uv-\int v' u\,dx$?

Comment: yes i do, in my textbook it is with f and g, so i was confused to what the meant with u and v

Comment: $u,v$ are equivalent to $f,g$. Both represent two functions (in terms of $x$)